# cordova-paramedic Info.plist not found

Tags: ios, cordova, testing, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

When running `cordova-paramedic --platform ios --plugin cordova-plugin-zencam  --verbose`.

This error appears:

```
No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-X, 12.1 simulator
/private/var/folders/_t/pxl23c8j27jbnnrmsmhl6qwc0001b8/T/tmp-25703ql9alOcv3wy6/platforms/ios/build/emulator/HelloCordova.app/Info.plist file not found.
Error: cordova emulate return error code 1
```

I have already tried to use `--buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'` and running the command this way,

`cordova-paramedic --platform ios --plugin cordova-plugin-zencam --args=--buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0' --verbose`

Another thing I have tried is running iOS on platform 5.0.0 this way,

`cordova-paramedic --platform ios@5.0.0 --plugin cordova-plugin-zencam  --verbose`

But then this errors appears,

```
cordova-paramedic: starting local medic server ios@5.0.0
(node:26754) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
platform is not supported :: ios@5.0.0
```

I found that a partial solution is adding `--justbuild` and running the following code,

`cordova-paramedic --platform ios --plugin cordova-plugin-zencam --verbose --justbuild  --args=--buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'`

However this is not an ideal solution because it only builds it, it won't let you run the tests.